# R :Plot and save in a pdf file

Tags: r

Write R code to draw sample of size 100 from N(0,1) and N(5,1) each . Plot the two figures on the same graph.Save the graph as `Sample.pdf` in the working directory `I`.

My attempt :

```
 pdf("SampleGraph.pdf",width=7,height=5)
 x=rnorm(100)
 y=rnorm(100,5,1)
 plot(x,lty=2,lwd=2,col="red")
 lines(y,lty=3,col="green")
 dev.off()
```

It's not working.

Comment: Maybe try: `plot(x,lty=2,lwd=2,col="red", ylim=c(-10,10)); points(y,lty=3,col="green")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works for me.

Check the working directory for the `Sample.pdf` file:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/user2983722/Documents"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the lack of green points on the plot, here is the fix:

```
plot(x,lty=2,lwd=2,col="red", ylim = c(min(x,y),max(x,y)))
points(y,lty=3,col="green")
```