# Print density plots (lattice, mice) on difference pages on PDF

Tags: r, pdf-generation, lattice, r-mice

I want to print the output from `densityplot()` from the `mice` package (`densityplot` method for `mids` objects), each to a separate page on a PDF. For the MWE below, I want to print one plot on each page (i.e., bmi on page 1, then hyp on page 2, then chi on page 3).

```r
library(mice)

imp <- mice(nhanes)

densityplot(imp)
```

[image: densityplots]

EDIT:

My slightly modified solution (to do this programatically):

```r
# Which variables had missing observations
imputed_vars <- names(d_imp$method)[d_imp$method != ""]

pdf(file = "./MICE Density Plots.pdf")

# Plot each imputed variable separately
for(var in imputed_vars){
  densityplot(d_imp, formula(paste("~", var)))
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: open a new graphics device for each plot?

Comment: How would I do that? I just call `densityplot()` once to produce all the plots

Comment: If you want document like that I'd use Rmd and the `\newpage` special: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240541/how-to-add-newpage-in-rmarkdown-in-a-smart-way. This is how you use a PDF graphics device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016215/r-plot-and-save-in-a-pdf-file

Comment: My question isn't about how to save output to a PDF, but how to specifically save the plots returned from `densityplot.mids()` to separate PDF pages. Run the MWE and you will see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean something like this:

```
imp <- mice(nhanes)
densityplot(imp)
densityplot(imp, ~bmi)
densityplot(imp, ~hyp)
densityplot(imp, ~chl)
```

BR